# Implementation firebase-ui and appcompat throws "requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-support-library, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with this implementation. The execution without using **firebase-ui**, as can be seen in the **Code 1**, works perfect

If I enable **firebase-ui** as shown in **Code 2**, it generates an error in the execution of **GetWindow**

Code 1:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //private Firebase mFirebaseRef;

    private ImageButton buttonMostrar;
    private ImageButton buttonMostrarJirafa;
    private ImageButton buttonMostrarPanda;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

     getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     ...
```

Code 2

```
  public class MainActivity extends FirebaseLoginBaseActivity {

    private Firebase mFirebaseRef;

    private ImageButton buttonMostrar;
    private ImageButton buttonMostrarJirafa;
    private ImageButton buttonMostrarPanda;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

      getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Error:

> ```
> 02-12 20:12:05.735 29271-29277/com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam
> ```
>
> E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
>       02-12 20:12:06.039 29271-29271/com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                               Process: com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam, PID:
>   29271
>                                                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam/com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam.MainActivity}:
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called
>   before adding content
>                                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                                                Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must
>   be called before adding content
>                                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:317)
>                                                                                                                   at
>   com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
>                                                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>                                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Note: the integration with **firebase-ui** alone works perfectly.

¿Ideas?

modification:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

now the error is over  **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/scrollGeneral">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear_general">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/login" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_tigre"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <ImageView android:contentDescription="@string/descripcionTigre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/imagenTigre"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tigre_10">


    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

        android:text="@string/valor_accion"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMostrar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textNombre"

        android:contentDescription="@string/descripcionTigre"
        android:src="@drawable/icon40x40">

    </ImageButton>



</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_jirafa"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    >

    <ImageView android:contentDescription="@string/descripcionJirafa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/imagenJirafa"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/jirafa_10">


    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

        android:text="@string/valor_accion_jirafa"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMostrarJirafa"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textNombre"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descripcionJirafa"
        android:src="@drawable/icon40x40"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_oso"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <ImageView android:contentDescription="@string/descripcionJirafa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/imagenOso"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/panda">


    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

        android:text="@string/valor_accion_panda"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMostrarPanda"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textNombrePanda"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descripcionPanda"
        android:src="@drawable/icon40x40"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_elefante"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/valor_accion_elefante"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMostrarElefante"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textNombre"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descripcionElefante" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

error:

> 02-12 21:00:05.780
>   23785-23785/com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                           Process: com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam, PID:
>   23785
>                                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam/com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
>   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
>                                                                                                               at
>   com.desarrollandolatam.nbortolotti.mobileacademialatam.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>                                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Fixed last error:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

rebuild and works!

Answer (score 2):

As per the error message:

> Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Instead, use [supportRequestWindowFeature()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#supportRequestWindowFeature(int)) before the `super.onCreate()` call:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Thanks ian! ... I changed the code, but now I have other error into setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);, I left the modification and the layout into the main post.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the new error message? At this point, it is a totally different question (one that has already been solved many times).

Comment: Yes true, but I'm afraid that the problem comes from "..extends FirebaseLoginBaseActivity" Can we discard that, right?

Comment: Doubtful you can remove it, if you want your Firebase login to work. Just follow the directions and use a Theme.Appcompat theme.

Comment: Done, I changed the style, rebuild and works..   <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> Thanks!